# Send image with Message UIActivity

Tags: ios

I'm using UIActivityViewController with some custom activities to send an image to DropBox and Instagram successfully.
Is there a way to send the same image (and text) inside n MMS message using the default UIActivity?

There's nothing in the documentation about this.

More info:
When I select Message from the `UIActiviViewController` pop-up only the text is sent - so something works - but not the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIActivity doesn't currently allow this feature for Messages, only text is allowed.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011974-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4

under constants UIActivityType Message, Supports NSString and Attributed String only, no UIImage

Comment: can you elaborate? how do you know this? is there anywhere mentioned in the documentation? I'm asking because you can send messages from some Apple apps - do they use some private API?